# Java TestNG with Data Driven Testing Across Multiple Tests

Tags: java, testng, data-driven-tests

I have a series of stores that I am testing in an ecommerce platform, and each store has a series of properties that I am looking at automating a test for. Is it possible to have a data provider that gives data across a test suite instead of just a test in TestNG? I'm trying not to use the testNG.xml file as mechanism because these properties are coming directly from a database call.

```
["StoreName", "username", "password", "credit-enabled", "items-store", "shipping-location", ]
```

What I need the automation to do is the following:

1. @Test Login with the username and password in the current dataset row.
2. @Test Verify the StoreName and items-store
3. @Test Navigate to the administration and verify that credit-enabled setting for the store and the shipping location of the store is correct given the items-store value.

But each step here would have to be its separate test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep dataprovider in a separate class and then annotate your tests with the dataprovider.  You can specify it using **dataProviderClass**

Quoting from testng doc [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders):

> By default, the data provider will be looked for in the current test
>   class or one of its base classes. If you want to put your data
>   provider in a different class, it needs to be a static method and you
>   specify the class where it can be found in the dataProviderClass
>   attribute:

```
public class StaticProvider {
  @DataProvider(name = "create")
  public static Object[][] createData() {
    return new Object[][] {
      new Object[] { new Integer(42) }
    }
  }
}

public class MyTest {
  @Test(dataProvider = "create", dataProviderClass = StaticProvider.class)
  public void test(Integer n) {
    // ...
  }
}
```